NoSuchMethodError when Exporting PDF with PrimeFaces and OpenPDF
I am working on a JSF application using PrimeFaces 14.0.3 for PDF exports.
                        <p:commandButton 
                            id="btnPdf" 
                            class="m-1 ui-button-info"
                            ajax="false"
                            rendered="true"
                            icon="fas fa-file-pdf"
                            value="Export as PDF">
                            <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="tbl" fileName="processional_fees" />
                        </p:commandButton>

When attempting to export a DataTable as a PDF, I encounter the following error:
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPCell com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.addCell(com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPCell)'
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.export.DataTablePDFExporter.addCell(DataTablePDFExporter.java:165)
    ...

Here's the relevant part of my pom.xml for PDF handling:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.librepdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>openpdf</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
</dependency>

I have also tried using openpdf version 2.0.3 based on the initial suggestion from PrimeFaces documentation which lists openpdf 1.4.1 for PDF exports. However, the error persists across both versions.
My environment includes:
PrimeFaces 14.0.3

JSF 2.3
Java 11
Payara 5

I am looking for guidance on how to resolve this NoSuchMethodError. Here are my questions:
Is there a known compatibility issue with openpdf and PrimeFaces 14.0.3 for PDF exports?
Could there be other dependencies in my project interfering with PDF generation?
Are there additional configurations needed in PrimeFaces or openpdf to handle PDF exports correctly?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

To me this error is quite suspicious

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPCell com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.addCell(com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPCell)'

In PR837: Modified PdfPTable add cell method to return cell a breaking change was made to return com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPCell when addCell is called. That was integrated with the 1.4.x releases. So it definitely should be there in 1.4.1 or 1.4.2
According to the error it can't find such a method signature. Thus I'd assume something in your setup is messing with the dependencies and introducing a com.github.librepdf version that doesn't have this breaking change (maybe a 1.3.X version)
Also the OpenPDF readme under Dependencies says

The 2.0.x Branch requires Java 17 or later.
The 1.4.x Branch requires Java 11 or later.
The 1.3.x Branch requires Java 8 or later.

so I would have expect 2.0.3 to not work at all, as you listed Java 11 for your environment.

Please try OpenPDF version 1.4.2
This should have been fixed in that version.
In general, I recommend using the latest version of Java (eg. Java 23) and the same for OpenPDF (eg. OpenPDF  2.0.3).
